# Removing N items from a list conditionally

Tags: .net

I was writing some **ASP.NET** control when I came to the scenario where I needed to remove items from a list, only when they matched a certain condition.

The `RemoveAll` method of the generic `List` class does a good job, but removes *all* items that match the condition, specified by the predicate.

What if I want to only remove a certain number of items specifying the condition? What do you think is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to specify both a limit for number of items to remove and a condition to select the items to remove, you can use this approach:

```
int limit = 30; // Suppose you want to remove 30 items at most
list.RemoveAll(item => ShouldIRemoveThis(item) && limit-- > 0);
```

Comment: lambda expressions are so kewl.

Answer (score 5):

@buyutec

Instead of

```
list.RemoveAll(item => ShouldIRemoveThis(item));
```

you can use:

```
list.RemoveAll(ShouldIRemoveThis);
```

The lambda has the same signature as the method, so they are equivalent so you can just pass the method directly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the method provides a "limit" parameter (which it doesn't) your best option is to go with a simple loop that removes the items that match, breaking when your incremented "match counter" hits your limit.

That's pretty much how the internal function works anyway, but in a more optimized way.

Answer (score 1):

In framework 3.5, RemoveAll method takes a predicate as a parameter. So you may use

```
list.RemoveAll(item => ShouldIRemoveThis(item));
```

where ShouldIRemoveThis is a method that returns a boolean indicating whether the item must be removed from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use LINQ? If so, you can just use the .Take() method and specify how many records you want (maybe as total - N).

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous delegates are useful here. A simple example to remove the first *limit* even numbers from a list.

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) myList.add(i);

int total = 0;
int limit = 5;
myList.RemoveAll(delegate(int i) { if (i % 2 == 0 && total < limit) { total++; return true; } return false; });

myList.ForEach(i => Console.Write(i + " "));
```

Gives 1 3 5 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19, as we want. Easy enough to wrap that up in a function, suitable for use as a lambda expression, taking the real test as a parameter.