# How do I remove an element that matches a given criteria from a LinkedList in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I have a LinkedList, where Entry has a member called id.  I want to remove the Entry from the list where id matches a search value.  What's the best way to do this?  I don't want to use Remove(), because Entry.Equals will compare other members, and I only want to match on id.  I'm hoping to do something kind of like this:

```
entries.RemoveWhereTrue(e => e.id == searchId);
```

edit: Can someone re-open this question for me?  It's NOT a duplicate - the question it's supposed to be a duplicate of is about the List class.  List.RemoveAll won't work - that's part of the List class.

Comment: Here's an answer to a duplicate question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460/removing-n-items-from-a-list-conditionally>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.Remove(list.First(e => e.id == searchId));
```

Comment: See my answer - the RemoveAll method actually accepts a predicate as a parameter.

Comment: Except there is no RemoveAll method on a LinkedList<T>.

Comment: This question is about a LinkedList, which doesn't have a RemoveAll method.

Comment: "although it does unfortunately require two iterations through the list rather than one as in my solution"

Nope. Remove(LinkedListNode<T>) is O(1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:

```
list.Remove(list.First((node) => node.id == searchId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Where extension method. You will get a new list (IIRC).